# ¿Cómo limpiar una variable tipo collection que adjunta archivos al enviar un correo en Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net

he creado un proyecto en vb.net para enviar archivos adjuntos a una lista de destinatarios, todo funciona bien excepto porque los archivos adjuntos se acumulan; Al primer destinatario le llega uno, al segundo dos, al tercero tres y así sucesivamente. Mi pregunta es: ¿Hay una forma de limpiar la variable de adjuntos para que no se acumule? Este es mi código:

Try

```
        Dim archivo As Net.Mail.Attachment = New Mail.Attachment(ruta)
        correo.To.Clear()
        correo.Body = ""
        correo.Subject = ""
        correo.To.Add(corr)
        correo.Body = mensaje
        correo.Subject = asunto
        Dim adju As New Net.Mail.Attachment(ruta)
        correo.Attachments.Add(adju)
        correo.IsBodyHtml = True
        correo.From = New MailAddress(emisor)
        envio.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(emisor, clave)
        'https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

        '
        envio.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
        envio.Port = 587
        envio.EnableSsl = True
        envio.Send(correo)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Mensaje", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

Comment: El código que muestras envía solamente un correo, sugiero que incluyas la parte que envía múltiples correos para ver dónde está el fallo. Sospecho que no es la variable `adju`. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes que limpiar la coleccion `correo.Attachments`. AL añadir cada anexo, lo estas añadiendo a una colección que mantiene los elementos previos.

Una buena práctica seria que para cada correo creases una instancia nueva de la clase que representa `correo`, de ese modo ese objeto estaria recien creado cada vez que has de enviar un correo y no tendrias ese problema.

De todos modos con el código que muestras, una forma rápida de solucionarlo seria añadiendo esta línea

```
        ...
        correo.Attachments.Clear() 'Limpiamos la colección Attachments
        correo.Attachments.Add(adju)
        ...
```